# How to upload file to a Google Brand Account without it counting on my storage?

Tags: google-drive, google-brand-account

I have access to a brand account with 1 TB of storage. My Google Drive is basic and has 15 GB and is almost over-quota. When I try to upload a file to the shared drive, I get "Not enough storage quota to upload. Upgrade Storage." [This thread](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsTo3c1fB1j_VPo/?hl=en) explains:

> If you are uploading the file, you are the owner and the storage counts against your quota.  There is no way to upload files to someone else's Drive space or to transfer ownership to someone else in consumer (private) Google accounts.  (There are some other options with G Suite accounts.)

I could not find if a brand account counts as a G Suite account, nor could I find a way to sign in to the brand account other than through my Google account.

How can I upload a file to a Google Brand Account without it counting on my storage?

Comment: You can't. Storage counts for any account accessing the shared content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solutions I found were:

- request login credentials for the brand account, create a new folder, and upload the files via the web browser;
- request someone with login access to create a new folder and copy or upload the files to that new folder.

Then the Brand account will own the files and they count against the brand account quota.

Anyone with access to the shared drive can remove the folder from syncing to their devices and the files will not count against their quota. They can still access the files from the web browser after signing-in. They can also share a read-only link for anyone without access.